# How to make layout using css flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

[image]

I am trying to make layout like showing in the picture using CSS.

HTML -

```
<section>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="column-row">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases1.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases2.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases3.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases4.jpg" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="column-row-2">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases5.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases6.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases7.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="./images/cases/cases8.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

        </div>


    </section>
```

CSS -

```
.row {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}



.column-row {
display: flex;
width: 25%;
max-width: 25%;}
```

.row should make the, two div placed as column,,two div on top of each other,Each div contain 4 images

Then .column-row should display 4 images in a row.. and should look like the picture attached..

I am new to css... I am not able to understand why my code is not working..Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like this?

I have removed your columns since they are unnecessary and set row to `flex-direction row` and added `flex-wrap` so they dont overflow.

I've reduced the width to 23% so that they have some space inbetween.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  width: 23%;
  max-width: 23%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is really an easy solution..The way i was doing was so complex.Thanks @Nicoshultz bro..

Comment: You are welcome :) I would recomend looking at Despina Kastani's `grid` answer too as `grid` is also good for this problem

Comment: Can you please suggest some resourse to learn css grid and flexbox..project based,, in project both grid and flexbox should be used.. Currently i am following a udemy course..It seems like they have implemented in  complex way.

Comment: I don't use grid so can't help you with that. This is the site I've used to understand flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: A rule-of-thumb: If you are adding widths to your flexbox contents then you need Grid

Comment: Here is Rachel Andrews amazingly helpful site for Grid : https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

And a while back I had to do a presentation for Modern CSS Layouts so I had created a collection on codepen with multiple examples: https://codepen.io/collection/naEzky

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are asking for Flexbox (and Nico Shultz has already posted a proper solution) may I suggest trying CSS Grid since it's more proper for the interface you are trying to implement?

Flexbox:

- One-dimensional layout
- Direction-agnostic
- Each line is calculated separately
- Works from the content out

Grid:

- Two-dimensional layout
- Works from the container in
- Separates element order in the source from visual

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This solutions works fine also...thanks @despina kastani

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your second DIV container has the class `.column-row-2`, for which there is no css rule - the existing CSS rule for `.column-row` won't apply here. So change the class for the second div to `column-row` to apply the same CSS to both.

Second, your second CSS rule (for `.column-row`) has `width: 25%;`, which sets the width of the *container div*  to 25%, which won't work as expected. So, instead, use thee two rules:

```
.column-row {
  display: flex;
}
.column-row > * {
  width: 25%;
}
```

The second of the rules will apply to the direct child elements, i.e. the images, and set their width to fit four into one row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the result you want.

I adjusted so that the images are responsive regardless of the device used. Remember, **you should also think about what the website will look like on smaller devices**, so you need a css rule that makes your images grouped in columns, not rows (in smaller devices).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        html, body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .row {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-left: -15px;
        }

        .column {
            -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
            flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
            max-width: 33.333333%;
        }

        @media (max-width: 702px) {
            .row {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/codepen.png" alt="Codepen Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/codepen.png" alt="Codepen Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/codepen.png" alt="Codepen Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/codepen.png" alt="Codepen Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/codepen.png" alt="Codepen Logo">
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/codepen.png" alt="Codepen Logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```css
.row {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}
.row img {
  display: flex;
width: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
flex: 0 0 25%
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry I am new to this thing there can be a mistake in my answer you can check this codepen  link https://codepen.io/sam-123/pen/eYBvood

Comment: I've made a edit for you so your code is in a snippet :) your code does work indeed

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was confused on how to write over here so I also attached the codepen link

Comment: whoever did this answer is not usefull please check the answer again it works I was unable to proper format it here that is why I also added a codepen link.